# Defining object of function prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to override a function of a object.

Have a look at this code:

```
var renderer = function(options) {

    this.options = options || {};
}


renderer.prototype.init = function() {

    if(this.options.make) {

        console.log('making ....');
    }
}
```

Now, my application code is :

```
 var myRendering = new renderer({make: true});

 var oldInit = myRendering.init;
 myRendering.init = function() {

    console.log('pre make stuff here');

    oldInit();
 }
```

Now, if i call

```
myRendering.init();
```

I get,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'make' of undefined
```

Expected output:

```
pre make stuff here    
making ....
```

I know, i can do it this way :

```
 var myRendering = new renderer({make: true});

 var oldRendering = new renderer({make: true});
 myRendering.init = function() {

    console.log('pre make stuff here');

    oldRendering.init();
 }
```

But is there any other way to define the options object in my **application code** without
creating an another copy of the object ?

Comment: You need to call `oldInit` with a `this`, which you can do by assigning it using `var oldInit = myRendering.init.bind(myRendering);`.

Comment: `oldInit.call(this);` Though you don't even need to cache the old version. Just go ahead and make the new `init()` method, and then do `renderer.prototype.init.call(this);`

Comment: Thanks, i really liked the method, where i didn't have to cache the object. Can you pst your comment as an answer, so that i can mark it as answered ?